# How to call jq in bash to store returned value in variable

Tags: bash, jq

I am trying to read json file and get a single object out of it, by reading that object into bash script variable.

Here how I was hoping to do that:

```
search_command="'.defines[] | select(.id==$current_id)'"
echo $search_command
out_json=`jq $search_command source.json`
```

where `current_id` is a variable with previously read id value. When I run this script, the output of the "debugging echo" is of expected value:

```
'.defines[] | select(.id==2)'
```

but after that, I get this message:

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting $end (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.defines[]
jq: 1 compile error
```

When I make a direct call in terminal with same parameters using:

```
jq '.defines[] | select(.id==2)' source.json
```

I see desired output.

I am quite new to bash scripting, so I can only guess that it's not jq part that is the source of problem, but the way I am trying to call it in bash. I've tried removing spaces inside the `search_command`, but that did not change much (this time error message had full contents of `search_command` in it, so I am guessing that this one is more valid, but still not valid enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use single quotes while defining `search_command` and enclose it in double quotes while referencing, like:

```
search_command=".defines[] | select(.id==$current_id)"
out_json="$(jq "$search_command" source.json)"
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked. I think I understand the problem a bit now. First the calling method (you've used array I did not think about), then removing unnecessary quote from argument. I'll have to properly start learning how to write bash scripts instead of just googling how to do only the part I need. In long run, this won't work well.

Comment: `$(...)` is not an array, it's the modern command substitution syntax

Comment: Sorry, I was so sure `shellcheck` warned of this. I conducted tests and result is identical with quotes or not. No `SC` for this. Note that both quoted and non-quoted work equally well in whatever shell I could test (ksh93, dash, ash, zsh, bash5). My apologies for the useless edit. It is only important if you need to expand the result into a list `for foo in $(command); ...` no quotes.

Comment: This is still subject to an injection "attack" if `current_id` has some more complex value than a simple integer, though.

Answer (score 0):

As with any other language, don't use string interpolation to define a command. Pass `current_id` as an argument to a *static* filter.

```
search_command='.defines[] | select(.id==$x)'
out_json=$(jq --argjson x "$current_id" "$search_command" source.json)
```